# Kafka does not always crash on failing flush

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have a Kafka topic named `a_topic_that_does_not_exist` and I want to publish a message to that topic using [Confluent Kafka Python client](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python).

As the name suggests, the above topic does not exist, so I expect to have errors in an attempt to publish it, since `auto.create.topics.enable=false` in Kafka server configuration file.

This is my snippet of code:

```
from confluent_kafka.cimpl import Producer

print('Creating producer')
producer = Producer(
            {
                'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka.foo.com:9092',
            }
        )
print('Producing message 1')
producer.produce('a_topic_that_does_not_exist', b'A message 1')
print('Flushing 1')
producer.flush()
print('Producing message 2')
producer.produce('a_topic_that_does_not_exist', b'A message 2')
print('Flushing 2')
producer.flush()
```

This is the output:

```
Creating producer
Producing message 1
Flushing 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
Producing message 2
  File "ISSUE.py", line 14, in <module>
    producer.produce('a_topic_that_does_not_exist', b'A message 2')
cimpl.KafkaException: KafkaError{code=_UNKNOWN_TOPIC,val=-188,str="Unable to produce message: Local: Unknown topic"}
```

As you may see, the first flush returned successfully, but the next publish failed. 
In addition to that, I can produce as many messages as I want before the first flush without experiencing any error.

All in all, the perceived behaviour seems to be the following:

1. I produce some messages for a non-existing topic
2. I flush
3. I produce another message for that topic -> ERROR

It would be nice to have that error at point 2 rather than at point 3.

More in general, how can I be sure that all the messages I produced have been published correctly?

My current solution is the following:

```py
import time

from confluent_kafka.cimpl import Producer

print('Creating producer')
producer = Producer(
            {
                'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka.foo.com:9092',
            }
        )
print('Producing message 1')


errors = []
def delivery_report(err, msg):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if err:
        errors.append(err)
    print('delivery_report({}, {})'.format(err, msg.value()))


for i in range(100):
    producer.poll(0)
    producer.produce('a_topic_that_does_not_exist', 'A message {}'.format(i), callback=delivery_report)
print('Flushing 1')
producer.flush()
if errors:
    raise ValueError
print('Producing message 2')
producer.produce('a_topic_that_does_not_exist', b'A message FINAL')
print('Flushing 2')
producer.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. From what I understand, the problem is with the Kafka configuration. In this case, Kafka doesn't allow the producer to create a new topic.
It is possible to configure Kafka to allow the producer to create new topics if they don't exist. As you mentioned, the problem arises when Kafka actually tries to enter the message by calling **flush()**. In this case, it might be a good idea to raise an exception "Topic could not be created" after calling **producer.produce(new_topic, message)**